# How can I remove stopwords in an efficient manner?

Tags: c#, performance, stop-words

How can i remove stopwords efficiently from a string. 
Right now I use this regex and it removed stopwords in less than a sec for a single string.

```
var STOPWORDPATTERN = @"(\b)(yourselves|you've|yourself|yours|.....)(/b)";

            value = Regex.Replace(
            value,
            STOPWORDPATTERN,
            DELIMITER_TOKEN,
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); //value is a string
```

However, I have like 2000 strings which took around 2s to process this function. And I would like to know if there are more efficient ways to deal with?

Comment: It depends how the regex engine loops through the input string. A faster approach may be to use regex to tokenise the input string into words, and have all your stop words stored in a HashSet which has binary search performance. Then just loop through the words & if they match a word in your stop word HashSet, append them onto a StringBuilder.

Comment: Would you like to improve algo or are you looking for a mass scale solution?

Comment: @AlexeyGroshev i think i am looking for a mass skill solution